# Best MailServer for Windows 2008 and integration with ASP.Net

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, email-server

I want to have an email server for my windows 2008 system.
The hard part is, that mailserver must have an API so I can create mailaccounts, send mails, read mails etc.etc (as e.g. hotmail.com so) from an asp.net page.

Comment: Lol, for what -1?

Comment: "I wanna" to start. Secons, why do you say "integration with ASP.NET". You need a mail server with an API and that is it. If anything then ".net", but not "asp.net".

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server has an [SMTP server built in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28WS.10%29.aspx). It uses Active Directory accounts, which can be scripted. [POP support has been discontinued](http://www.iishacks.com/2008/07/22/pop3-protocol-missing-in-windows-2008-iis7/), but there [are alternatives](http://weblogs.asp.net/hpreishuber/archive/2008/04/30/visendo-smtp-pop3-extender-for-windows-2008-server.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try [smartermail](http://www.smartertools.com/). It's free for a single domain.